# Ionic 2 - How to create dynamic template to compile dynamic component

Tags: typescript, compilation, ionic2, angular2-compiler

I want to **dynamically** create a template. 
I found a resolution that works with Angular 2.0, this resolution uses a JiT compiler.
[Link to resolution in Angular 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009)

My question is, how to make dynamically created template using Ionic 2? 
Can I use JiT compiler like in Angular 2.0?